# copy a stream via byte[]

Tags: java, byte, inputstream

Hiho,

i have to copy an inputstream. And after a bit of searching in the net, i tried this with the help of a bytearray. My code looks like this("is" is the inputstream):

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while (is.read() != -1) {
        bos.write(is.read());
    }
    byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray(); 

    InputStream test = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);
    InputStream test2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(ba);
```

And it works.. nearly

In both the stream, the programm copied only every second character
So "DOR A="104"/>" in the "is"-stream becomes:
"O =14/"
in the other streams

What is the Problem? i can not understand what is going on.

Hope anybody could give me the solution:)

greetings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to assign the read byte in the `while` loop to a variable. In your current code you just discard it. The following is correct:

```
int b;
while((b = read()) != -1) {
    bos.write(b);
}
```

Of course reading single bytes is not very efficient. You should consider using byte arrays in your next version.

Comment: Thanks very much! i understand what was the problem:)
(because i used the read method two times it jumps two times)

Comment: It is not correct. It doesn't compile. You can't declare a variable inside a while condition.

Comment: @EJP: Then why did you rollback your correction (and probably chose to downvote instead)?

Comment: I rolled back my correction and downvoted because of your mistake. You're free to fix it yourself.

Comment: @EJP You're not making any sense. Also, this is a wiki. Correcting and then rolling back is really erratic. Why make the effort of fixing it in the first place then?

Comment: @musiKk No, this is not a wiki. You are still free to fix your mistake. You've known about it long enough.

Answer (score 16):

That's because you ignored all the odd characters unless they were -1, by calling read() twice in your loop. Here's the correct way using a buffer (you can tune the buffer size):

```
int count;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
  out.write(buffer, 0, count);
```